# I want the Left 10 characters of the name column calculated in another column

Tags: calculated-column

A lot our names on SP are real long names; I would like to get say the left 10 (or any number of characters I put in the formula) characters of the name to calculate into a column. This would make looking through the file names faster.

Comment: try sorting the view by name?

Comment: If I understand the question, OP is asking for a calculated field formula to grab a substring of a field.  OP can correct me if I'm wrong.  Hope that clears it up for the person who voted to close.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new calculated column and use the `LEFT` function to return portions of another field, just like Excel. For the value of your new calculated column use the formula:

```
=LEFT([Col1],10)
```

Where `Col1` is the name of the field you want to retrieve data from and `10` is the number of characters. Replace both items to suite your needs.

I also strongly encourage anyone looking for more information about calculated columns to check out the MSDN reference at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: This is a more complete (and correct) list: http://viewmaster365.com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List

Comment: The result of `=LEFT([DOB],3)` where the `DOB` column value is `1/18/1950` is, incorrectly, `182`, plus the square brackets are stripped when saving the column.  **edit**: even just using `[DOB]` as the formula returns `18,281`.

Comment: ps to above - needed to use [text() excel function](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/04/08/convert-date-text-excel/) to convert date to text , so here is a formula that creates client reference from date of birth, first letter of first name and first three letters of surname, in upper case:  `=UPPER(TEXT(DOB,"ddmmyy")&LEFT(Name,1)&LEFT(Surname,3))` , eg:  `180150JSMI`.

Comment: and here is a good reference for available functions:  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/examples-of-common-formulas-in-sharepoint-lists-d81f5f21-2b4e-45ce-b170-bf7ebf6988b3